# How to delete similar elements from String array or ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I'm totally new to programming and I have String array:

```
String dates[] = {"01-01-1993", "19-11-1993", "01-01-1993", "03-03-2000", "03-03-2000"};
```

In the above array `dates[0] == dates[2]` and `dates[3] == dates[4]`, I want to delete the duplicate values which **IS REPEATED** and I want program to produce result like this:

```
dates[] = {"01-01-1993", "19-11-1993", "03-03-2000"}
```

Some are using `ArrayList` concept some are using complex `for loops` and I'm confused, so could you please help in achieving the above task.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Are you forced to use an array?  Could you just use a HashSet which would not allow duplicates in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to remove duplicates.

```
Set<T> dateSet = new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(dates));
```

dateSet will only contain unique values.

If you need to get back to an array

```
dates = dateSet.toArray(new String[dateSet.size()]);
```

Comment: or LinkedHashSet to preserve order

Answer (score 5):

Your question raises a few points:

1. In general, this kind of manipulation of collections is much easier and cleaner if you use the Collection classes (Set, List, etc). For example, a Set guarantees uniqueness of the elements:

   ```
   String dates[] = {"01-01-1993", "19-11-1993","01-01-1993","03-03-2000","03-03-2000"};
   Set<String> uniqueDates = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(dates));
   ```

But HashSet is unordered; if you iterate over uniqueDates the order in which you get the back is arbitrary. If the order is important, you could use LinkedHashSet:

```
Set<String> orderedUniqueDates = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(dates));
```

2. The basic collection that come with Java are pretty good; but if you use Google's Guava library (https://github.com/google/guava), it gets *really* nice and you can do really powerful things like finding intersections of sets, set differences etc.:

   ```
   Set<String> uniqueDates = Sets.newHashSet(dates);
   ```
3. More fundamentally, String is a very poor choice of data type to represent Dates. Consider using either java.util.Date or (if using a Java version prior to 8) org.joda.time.DateTime (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Not only will this give you type safety and ensure that your data is really all dates, but you could then do things like sorting.

Comment: Or even much better Java 8 `java.time` package.

Comment: Your code is good ... Using LinkedHashSet we can get sorted list

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 you can do the following:

```
String dates[] = {"01-01-1993", "19-11-1993", "01-01-1993", "03-03-2000", "03-03-2000"};
dates = Arrays.stream(dates).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Your code is too simplified Thanks buddy :) It's working

Answer (score 1):

this will work simply

```
 Set<T> tempSet= new HashSet<T>(Arrays.asList(dates));
    String[] dates= tempSet.toArray(new String[tempSet.size()]);//copy distinct values
```

Comment: Wow Rajan Thanks a Lot .. Your's code is simplified too.